# Django shell writes record in wrong db

Tags: django

There are two projects in our server: the first project is test project,
the second project is not test project. All projects uses mssql db. The first project uses test db, the second project uses db that is not test. The first project reads environment variables from .env file. The second project reads environment variables from .bash_profile. When I ran django shell in the first project and created record using sql query record was created in db that is not test. How could this happen?

Comment: to me looks like a messed up settings.py file
already checked that? (p.e. file has been pasted one project to another)
also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: I missed one detail: when I run docker-compose and open browser everything works correct in both projects

Comment: Both projects works simultaneously. .bash_profile is in home folder and than projects are in different folders.  When I found my test records in production, hm, well that scared me.